# Modal closing upon delete function within a card in React. Why?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, redux-toolkit

I have a modal that is triggering when someone presses a 'Member' button in the navigation. The modal works fine and contains cards that list all the members. Code is here (styled components might make the jsx tags look odd but it's fine)

```js
const cards = members.map((member, i) => (
    <Card key={i}>
      <Name>{member.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + member.name.slice(1)}</Name>
      <Relationship>
        {member.relationship.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
          member.relationship.slice(1)}
      </Relationship>
      <ButtonContainer>
        <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "#05848c" }} onClick={ () => handleAddInfo(member._id)}>Add Info</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(member._id)}>Delete</Button>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </Card>
  ));
```

If I just have a console log in the 'handleDelete', the button on any card can be pressed and the modal is fine. However when I dispatch a 'delete member' event, the function works but the modal abruptly shuts down. I can't figure out what might be triggering this and have searched everywhere for an answer. Does anyone have any clues why that might be? Here is the delete function in Redux Toolkit

```js
const deleteMember = async (memberId, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/me/family/${memberId}`, config);
  return response.data;
};
```

Comment: Can you share handleDelete() function ?

Comment: const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
   dispatch(deleteMember(id))
  }

Comment: I'm also having this issue when submitting an add member form in the modal too so I think there is something that is happening upon dispatch that is shutting down the modal but have zero idea why.....

Comment: Well if anyone is having this problem - I made the modal into a page and problem solved....